# SpringREST - RequestMethod.PUT not working

Tags: spring-security, spring-rest

I have created a SpringREST API using SpringBoot 1.2.6.
Below is my post method and it works. But when i created a Put method, its not working. Its not fetching the data in paramaters.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String createArticle(String article_name, String article_content, Long image_id, String category,
                                HttpServletRequest req, Authentication authentication) throws Exception {...}
```

**PUT METHOD**
// Edit Articles

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{article_id}",
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String editArticle(@PathVariable("article_id") Long article_id,
                          String article_name, String article_content, String category, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {...}
```

I have set the debugger, and below is the debug snapshot
[Debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfGt.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more information about the use of this API. Example of requests that you are using would be useful.

Comment: There are no parameters. Those should be annotated with `@RequestParam` next to that you should have the `HttpPutFormContentFilter` registered as a filter to be able to parse request params.

Answer (score 0):

By using `PUT` method, it's not supporting in spring boot. Whether I need to add any new configuration.

Put method works only the request not have any parameters. If I add any query parameter or form data it doesn't work.

You will implementing like below code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)

public @ResponseBody String createArticle(@RequestBody CreateArticle request) {
    LOG.info(request.toString());
    return "ok";
}
```

In that `CreateArticle` is request class which pass value in json format and including all parameters like String `article_name`, String `article_content`, Long `image_id`, String `category`, `HttpServletRequest req`, Authentication `authentication`.